# jQuery ajax.load div, then have parent container access property

Tags: jquery

So I have a tabbed ui "form", each tab is quiet complicated so it is loaded via the .load('item.html'); command.

All good, when the user clicks to a different tab, I want to read a property, maybe execute a function from within the ajax loaded div.

What is the best way to get to these properties and methods from outsite the ajax loaded div?

Answer (score 1):

The [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function provides a third parameter representing a callback which will be executed when the ajax call completes. You could use it to execute some arbitrary function:

```
$('#id').load('item.html', { }, function() {
    alert('tab loaded');
});
```

Comment: Hi, sorry probably explained this wrong, I will re-post asking a different way